# CSS3 Transition Flash

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

[Does anybody know why this is happening?](http://cl.ly/LnZb)

On all the anchors, I have:

```
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
```

Why is that 'flash' occurring?

### Update

By flash, I mean where the the H1 goes from purple to white.

### Update 2

It seems to happen almost all anchor links.

For the example which is the logo, the HTML is:

```
<h1 class="logo"><a href="/">Test</a></h1>
```

In the CSS I have:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

The h1 is in header and for the header, I have certain CSS for the header links:

```
.header a {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

And for the h1, I have:

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  font-family: "proxima-nova";
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is transitioning on this page? Also,you should post your HTML for future users who might see this question.

Comment: I visited your page and I saw no 'flash' of any kind (Chrome 22/Win 7).

Comment: A jsFiddle demo would be great.

Comment: with transition: all you animate/change everything you changed maybe only use transition: color and it would be helpful if you post a link to your site or create a jsfiddle or some code

Comment: @DanielKurz I'm working locally and couldn't duplicate it in jsfiddle. What part of the code do you wanna know?

Comment: If you can't create a fiddle, please give us the full CSS code that applies to the test item, and the HTML code that accompanies it.

Comment: this is how a jsfiddle looks like with the code you provided: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ldaniell14260/nxCnS/)

Comment: Why are you setting transition properties if you have no `:hover` state ?

Comment: @DanielKurz It seems to happen when I refresh the page fresh

Comment: @elias94xx In the header, on hover on the h1 a, the opacity goes to .8

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nxCnS/1/